# Assign a string value to a toggle switch in swiftui

Tags: swiftui, toggle

i have a form that works correctly but would like to add a toggle to indicated if a garment is used or new. if it is new toggle on, if its used a condtion box will show where the user can input the garments condition.

when then toggle is on, i would like to set the value to static string value of "New"

code i have tried:

```
Form{
 VStack {
                        Toggle(isOn: self.$itemNew) {
                                  Text("is the item new?")
                             self.$Cond == "New"
                              }

                              if !itemNew {
                                TextField("Item Condition:", text: self.$Cond) {}
                              }
                          }
}
```

that code didnt seem to work, any pointers on where i should be looking to solve this one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a $, you can create a Binding manually like this:

```
Toggle(isOn: Binding(get: {self.cond == "New" ? true : false},
    set: {
        if newValue == true{
             self.cond == "New"
        }else{
            self.cond == "Not really new"
        }
    })) {
        Text("is the item new?")
    }
```

And the self.cond is still must be a @State variable to trigger View update its visual presentation.
But your case isn't look very ordinary for that instrument. Is there other possible values of the string?